# Is there a way to use strings to name eshells

Tags: eshell

I know a numeric prefix will create (or switch to) a new eshell session with that number. Is there a way to assign a string instead of a number?

For example, normally I get the following:

```
*eshell*<1>
*eshell*<2>
*eshell*<3>
*eshell*<4>
```

I would like

```
*eshell*<project1/source>
*eshell*<project1/doc>
*eshell*<project2/source>
*eshell*<project2/doc>
```

I figure I can use counsel to quickly switch between a large number of eshells.

My ultimate goal is to have a command say `eshell-dir`. It will parse out the last 2 or 3 directories from `default-directory` and create the *eshell* string. Then I can either switch to that eshell session if it exists or I can open a new eshell session with the name *eshell*.

Even better yet if the name could use `uniquify` that would be amazing!

I figure if I get this to work, I can do 90% of my shell work in emacs which would be a huge plus for me.

Comment: I use the following way to rename buffers in general with `C-mouse-1` in the mode line identification (i.e., the buffer name). I create a new eshell-buffer and rename so it afterwards. `(defun mode-line-rename-buffer (e)
  "Just like 'rename-buffer' only do it with the buffer of the window of the clicked mode-line"
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((buf (window-buffer (posn-window (event-start e)))))
    (when buf
      (with-current-buffer buf
 (call-interactively 'rename-buffer)))))
(define-key mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap (kbd "<mode-line> <C-mouse-1>") 'mode-line-rename-buffer)`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want?  Using a number is hardcoded into the `eshell` function, but you could easily write your own version that handles things differently.

Comment: The question has been updated with an example. Thanks Qudit

Comment: You can try to implement your idea by yourself and if you encounter a problem, ask that one instead.

Comment: That was the plan but I got stuck on the string assignment of the name. I will read the blog posted below and try some things. I will post back my findings.

Answer (score 2):

there is a nice blog article about eshell here : http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/eshell-fun.html

In this post, he describes a function named "eshell-here". I think you can basically adapt it by using uniquify.